# Array of Objects inside another object - PHP

Tags: php

My problem is below:

```
class AClass{
   BClass objB;
   CClass objC = array();
}

$objC1 = new CClass();

$objC1->x = data; .....

$objA1 = new AClass();
$objA1->objC[] = $objC1;
```

So what i want to do is, there is an array of CClass objects, which should go inside AClass.

Tries arrayobjects, push etc. no luck.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do you mean by no luck ? where is the problem ?

Comment: PHP does not have strongly typed class members. Your syntax is also missing `$` variable prefixes

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Just change `CClass objC = array();` to `public $objC = array()` and then you can push to the array.

Comment: Extremely sorry for this mess up. Infact my psuedo code was correct, and the actual had some error, in terms of object name and where i was doing var_dump. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, PHP does not support typed class properties. I would control access to the `objC` property via methods which [can have typed arguments](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.typehinting.php). For example

```
class AClass {
    private $objB;
    private $objC = array();

    public function addC(CClass $obj) {
        $this->objC[] = $obj;
    }
}

$objA1 = new AClass;
$objA1->addC($objC1);
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for this mess up. Infact my psuedo code was correct, and the actual had some error, in terms of object name and where i was doing var_dump. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Phil, thanks for the repsonse. Appreciates it.